# R - Read foreign language data from HIVE and Write to MySQL

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, utf-8, hive

I have some English as well as some Hindi data in my HIVE tables. I use R to connect to HIVE and read this data and then do some processing using dataframes and then I want to write this data to a table in MySQL database.

I am able to connect to HIVE from R and then I run a `df <- dbGetQuery(conn, <Select Query>)` command to extract data from HIVE table. I see that the resulting dataframe has only the Unicode values of the Hindi characters and not the actual Hindi characters. How do I preserve the original data?

Plus, I have a lot of processing steps of this data before I write the output to MySQL. How do I ensure that Hindi characters are preserved all throughout?

Comment: _"resulting dataframe has only the Unicode values of the Hindi characters and not the actual Hindi characters"_ > what is the difference? And what flavor of Unicode are you talking about? Hive expects all characters to be stored as UTF-8 without BOM, by default. If the original text used another encoding, then Hive will spit is out as-is.

Comment: _"I see that..."_ > which tool do you use to "see"? Did you make sure the tool correctly adapts to the code page used by MySQL _(set at column level, or DB level)_ or by Hive _(set at table level with custom SerDe, or UTF-8 by default)_?

Comment: Maybe I didn't put it across the right way. I meant that the dataframe has the <U+xxxx> kind of values and not the actual hindi character.

Comment: I am using RStudio to see the dataframe. I've also tried using Rscript on windows command prompt to run the R command set. Both resulted in me losing hindi characters.

Comment: Did you try to query Hive directly on a Linux prompt? Because I suspect your data was already f*ed up at the time it was loaded into the Hadoop cluster  :-(

Comment: Well .. data is just fine in Hive. I am able to extract it into text files as well.